# Replacement for pydoc showing only function signatures

Tags: python, command-line, bash

I want to find alternative for pydoc (command line tool to generate documentation for python modules) which additionally allow optionally (with keyword argument) hide docstring (show only function and class signatures).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked (nor is "for example" ;). You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.